# Multiple Sites in Django

Tags: django, apache, virtualhost

Does anyone know how to add multiple domains to Django.
I've tried following the guides here [Multiple Sites under single Django project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369486/multiple-sites-under-single-django-project) with no luck.

My configuration looks like this

**Settings**

/opt/django/project/settings.py

/opt/django/project/domain1_settings.py

**Url**

/opt/django/project/urls.py

/opt/django/project/domain1_urls.py

**wsgi**

/opt/django/project/domain1/domain1.wsgi

**Apache**

/etc/httpd/conf.d/django.conf

```
<VirtualHost * >
  ServerName domain1.co.uk
  ServerAlias www.domain1.co.uk direct.domain1.co.uk
  WSGIDaemonProcess domain1 processes=5 python-path=/usr/bin/python threads=1
  WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/django/project/domain1/domain1.wsgi
  ErrorLog logs/domain1-error.log
  CustomLog logs/domain1-access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

When I restart apache i see no errors but when I go to the site I am sent to the (non django) domain that is configured within the main httpd.conf.

Thanks,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This answer makes the assumption that you want to have two domain names each running separate Django projects, but being hosted from the same Apache server. If this isn't the case, please refine your question!

To start with you'll need two `VirtualHost` entries in your apache conf (let's call your sites `domain1.co.uk` and `domain2.co.uk`)

```
# Virtual hosts setup
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName domain1.co.uk

    WSGIDaemonProcess APPLICATION_NAME processes=5 python-path=/opt/django/project/domain1:/home/USERNAME/webapps/APPLICATION_NAME/lib/python2.6     threads=1
    WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/django/project/domain1/domain1.wsgi
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName domain2.co.uk

    WSGIDaemonProcess APPLICATION_NAME_www processes=5 python-path=/opt/django/project/domain2:/home/USERNAME/webapps/APPLICATION_NAME/lib/python2.6 threads=1
    WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/django/project/domain2/domain2.wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```

You'll also need 2 wsgi files (pointed two in the conf above)

```
/opt/django/project/domain1/domain1.wsgi
/opt/django/project/domain1/domain2.wsgi
```

and will look something like

```
import os
import sys
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project.settings' 
# or     project.domain1_settings
application = WSGIHandler()
```

Onto the `settings.py` make sure that both settings files have difference `SITE_ID = 1` or `SITE_ID = 2` and that you point to the correct `urls.py`

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls'
```

or

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'domain1_urls'
```

Much of this question has been sourced from personal experience and this [blog](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2010/10/19/run-multiple-websites-one-django-project/) post. Your project directories and domain names seem to be a little confusing, I've done my best to fit them into the correct places here, but you will need to adjust for your own purposes.

**Additional**

If you have two sites running from the same server, you will have to be very careful to maintain consistency over project directories, static file directories and settings files etc. 
From your question you say your settings files are `/opt/django/project/settings.py` and  `/opt/django/project/domain1_settings.py` This is quite confusing as it seems that you have one project directory (`/opt/django/project`). I would strongly recommend stronger separation; as I describe above, maybe setting your projects (`domain1` and `domain2`) in directories

```
/opt/django/project/domain1/
/opt/django/project/domain2/
```

with corresponding settings files

```
/opt/django/project/domain1/settings.py
/opt/django/project/domain2/settings.py
```

etc. This should make it easier to spot what is going wrong where.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Ive added the settings that you suggested but Im seeing a 500 erro via apache. When going through the logs it shows that the it is unable to import my new settings file.
The new settings file is within the maint project folder and I have the line added within my wsgi file pointing to it  ---->
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'domain1_settings'

Thanks,

Comment: After adding the correct sys path to my wgsi file and making sure all of my project/app imports were constant everything started working.
Many Many Thanks...